# jquery form validation plugin rule to check value of field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to just check the value of two form fields in my jquery validation plugin.

I know I can do it by adding new methods (jQuery.validator.addMethod()), but surely there's a way in my rules declaration to just check the value of these fields?

ie:

```
rules: {
            bothSelected: { value: "0" },
            neitherSelected: { value: 0 }
        },
```

I can't seem to find a way to verify the value.  I this not possible?

Comment: Not sure... are you asking us to look through [the list of available rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/) for you?  Otherwise, you should explain better about what kinds of values the field should pass... strings, numbers, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/#range-method

`range: [0,0]` will require that the field's value be between 0 and 0.  It's inclusive, so `[0,0]` can only be satisfied by `0`.

```
rules: {
    myFieldName: {
        range: [0,0]
    }
}
```